# Convert node orientation from one parent to another parent in SceneKit

Tags: swift, scenekit, quaternions

What I'm looking for is a method `SCNNode.convertOrientation(_:to)`, which would work similarly to `SCNNode.convertPosition(_:to)` or `SCNNode.convertTransform(_:to)`, only for a rotation/orientation.

I first tried

`node.simdOrientation = from.simdWorldOrientation / to.simdWorldOrientation * orientation`

but that doesn't seem to work. The only way I could make it work was by using a temporary node on which to do the whole transform conversion, which seems unnecessarily inefficient. (In the code below I'm also converting the node's position, which I put there just to visually check that the whole conversion was successful.)

```
node.position = to.convertPosition(node.position, from: from)
let temp = SCNNode()
temp.setWorldTransform(node.worldTransform)
temp.transform = temp.convertTransform(SCNMatrix4Identity, to: to)
node.simdOrientation = temp.simdOrientation
node.removeFromParentNode()
to.addChildNode(node)
```

Is there a particular reason why there is no built-in method for doing this? Am I not supposed to do this at all?

Comment: hey you need a temporary node to traslate that will be your axis in X, Y

Comment: I don't understand. I'm already using a temporary node. What exactly do you mean?

Comment: need a little bit more clarification on what exactly you want to do. What should be the effect? what I understand: You hava a from node and a to node. And you have your other node on which you want to change the orientation (but not position or size). Should the effect (orientation change) happen insantainously or over time?

Comment: It should happen instantaneously. The code I used as an example in the question should effectively not move the node visually, just as if using `from.convertTransform(node.transform, to: to)`, but in the end I need the converted orientation for something else. I’m calculating an orientation in the coordinate space of a node and need to have it in the coordinate space of another one.